# Laravel 5: Move public folder or .htaccess rules?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I'm curious and new with Laravel.

So,  I made fresh installation of Laravel 5. 
Actually, my project is accessable through index.php in public folder.

For this moment, i put all files in htdocs folder in my lampp stack.

What is best practice to load the project through http://localhost, not
http://localhost/public

Can I move all files in public folder to root dir or is not good idea? May be .htaccess rule is better solution?
What are the advantages and disadvantages in every case?

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to configure virtual hosts to get rid of the trailing directory. Just deal with it for the time being, as when you deploy it won't be there.

Comment: What about I want to move on the project in live server? What could be the solution?

Comment: It depends on whether you are allowed to modify Apache configuration to include vhosts settings. If not, moving the contents in public/ out of public/ is one option, like I did.

Answer (score 0):

for Windows, try create symbolic link on directory, for example:

`mklink /D www x:\path\to\laravel\public\`